# Phrase match in a sentence using R

Tags: r, regex, gsub

I need to match multiple phrases in a sentence using R and save it in columns beside it. Example:

```
   sentence <- c("My CPU is working but keyboard is not working", "unable
                  access printer", "unable access printer and keyboard is not working")  
   phrase   <- c("unable access printer", "keyboard is not working")
```

I want my output in below data frame format:

```
      sentence                                             phrase1                  phrase2
  My CPU is working but keyboard is not working         keyboard is not working       NA
  unable access printer                                      NA                       NA
  unable access printer and keyboard is not working     unable access printer        keyboard is not working
```

Request you to please guide me with the approach or R code. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, i have tried but still not getting the output in desired format. It will be very helpful if you can guide me with the code.

Comment: you should post the code you have tried in your question.

Comment: Maybe just `res <- sapply(phrase, grepl, x = sentence); rownames(res) <- sentence; res`? I think this format will be more handy for whatever you plan to do with the result.

Comment: Thanks lukeA. Your code has given me some direction to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(quanteda)
library(foreach)
library(data.table)

corp = corpus(sentence)

find.phrases = foreach(i = 1:length(phrase)) %do% {
  kwic(corp, phrase[i])
}

find.df = rbindlist(find.phrases)
```